# Updating all other list items

Tags: list, infopath, updatelistitems

Ok, so I want to use a sharepoint list as a ticketing system.  One of the fields is priority.  I want this field to automatically update if, for instance, I input a new item with a priority of 2 I would like the current ticket that is priority 2 to change to 3 and so on for all numbers greater than 2.  I can kind of envision the logic but I can't find anywhere a function that will call the last edited item.  There probably is an easier way than what I'm thinking of but I can't find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ItemAdded` event receiver.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

    SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
    int priority = item["priority"];
    SPList li = properties.List;
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = '<Where><Geq><FieldRef Name = "Priority"/><Value Type="number">'+priority+'</Value></Geq></Where>'
    SPListItemCollection coll = li.GetItems(query);
    for(int i=0; i<coll.Count;i++)
    {
        \\update the required items here
    }
}
```

P.S. The above code might not be completely accurate. It is just intended to provide some pointers. Hopefully it helps..:)